# cygwin mkgroup (272): [1707] The network address is invalid

Tags: cygwin

I installed cygwin64 and I tried to execute the command

$ mkgroup -l /etc/group

but I get the error

```
SYSTEM:S-1-5-18:18:
NT SERVICE+TrustedInstaller:S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-1853292631-2271478464:328384:
mkgroup (272): [1707] The network address is invalid.
```

Following is what I have done upto now.

```
Copying skeleton files.
These files are for the users to personalise their cygwin experience.

They will never be overwritten nor automatically updated.

'./.bashrc' -> '/home/saiki//.bashrc'
'./.bash_profile' -> '/home/saiki//.bash_profile'
'./.inputrc' -> '/home/saiki//.inputrc'
'./.profile' -> '/home/saiki//.profile'

saiki@MSaiki ~
$ mkpasswd -l > /etc/passwd

saiki@MSaiki ~
$ mkgroup -l /etc/group
SYSTEM:S-1-5-18:18:
NT SERVICE+TrustedInstaller:S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-1853292631-2271478464:328384:
mkgroup (272): [1707] The network address is invalid.
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: may be `mkgroup -l > /etc/group` ? Anyway read https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-how as `/etc/group` and `/etc/passwd` are not strictly needed

Comment: it worked. thank u :)